# Adding app shortcut on lockscreen

Tags: java, android, lockscreen

I want to add my app's shortcut on phone's lock screen, is it possible in android ? Below screenshot (which is of iPhone) will make it clear.
Without Widget..

[image: iOS screenshot]

Any help will be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a shortcut in the home-screen then that is obviously possible with the API Android provides.

But you are talking about adding a shortcut to the lock-screen, which only a few (very few) Android devices support officially. I have experience with a lot of different Android devices from a lot of different manufacturers but **none of them supports adding an app shortcut** on the lockscreen.

You might not be willing to accept my answer as may not provide the answer you were looking for, but still I would try to give you **two possible solutions** :-

1) You need to create your own lockscreen for this and then you obviously have the privilege of adding any shortcut you want there. See if that's a possible solution for you.

2) Or, if know of any Android device that does support this, then you need to contact the device manufacturer for knowing the API.

I am rest assured there is no official API available to put an app shortcut on the lockscreen.

Hope I could help you with my best.

Comment: Thank you @Aritra Roy for giving your precious time and suggesting some solution.

Comment: Please do accept the answer as I tried to provide you with the best possible solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this article at: http://fieldguide.gizmodo.com/put-your-key-apps-on-the-android-lock-screen-for-easy-a-1621573474. Following these steps should get you what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @thestepafter for responding, but is it possible without widget